# Why is the chat window showing my wrong reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, chat

In this window

https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/131427

It is showing my reputation as 259,

[image] but when I click on my name(Outofmemory), it shows my reputation as 98.
[image]

My question: Why is it showing different reputation as in the above images ?

Please let me know if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three chats: chat.stackoverflow.com for Stack Overflow, chat.meta.stackexchange.com for Meta, chat.stackexchange.com for all other sites.

You are looking on the last one. This global chat profile shows your *global* reputation (sum of reputations of all of your accounts), which is exactly 259.

Comment: Ah I see. I was actually confused by seeing the SO logo and thought that I had 259 rep on SO

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at your chat.stackexchange.com profile. Chat.SE profiles show your total network rep, which is 259 rep. If you would go to your chat.stackoverflow.com profile, you would see 98 rep.

Answer (score 0):

That images clearly shows answer for your question.

Actually you have Account in **Stack Exchange** network which have many sites, **Chat, Meta, Stack Overflow** are one of it.

It shows your overall reputations in Stack Exchange as 259 and in only on Stack Overflow as 98 reputations.

By default or by logged in through Stack Exchange it shows your overall reputations in Stack Exchange.

When you moved to Stack Overflow by click on your name, it shows your Stack Overflow's reputation. Thats all..

And you can see the user's all site contribution details and reputations in each accounts in Stack Exchange.

Comment: There is no such thing "Stack Exchange account". Stack Exchange is a network of many sites, one can have account on any of them.

Comment: @Shadow yes, I came to told that only in another way. I know SE is a network which have many sites in it. But you should have an account or an openID to logged in SE or in its sites. Thats what I said account in SE.

Comment: True but Stack Exchange account isn't a real account, it doesn't have reputation of its own. Anyway others gave the correct answer 10 minutes before you posted this.